# Reliable file transfer over slow or flaky network link

Tags: ssh, scp, upload, failsafe

I need to transfer a number of files files over a low-quality broadband link to a server.  The files are large, and take approximately 30 minutes to transfer per file.

I use scp, but it sometimes hangs -- the transfer doesn't fail with an error, it keeps running, but no further data is transferred.

So, I'm looking for a "failsafe" upload solution, one that will work even if the link fails for a few minutes or is otherwise unreliable.

My idea is:

1. split big file in small parts
2. upload parts, with timeout and retry if fail

Questions:

- is there a ready-to-run tool that implements this idea? (no specific need for scp. could be ftp or anything else)
- is there a way to detect when scp hangs? ((that is, it is still running, but does not transfer data)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use rsync to copy your file from one computer to the other. rsync can use ssh as its underlying transport. Combine `rsync --partial` with a script such as [this one](https://superuser.com/a/302843/144961) to try again in case of network failure, and you should be able to move your files even in the face of network errors.

Another way to do it would be to mount the remote filesystem on your local computer with `sshfs -o reconnect`, and then just cp the file(s). sshfs/Linux will take care of the rest. Based on some testing I did today, this seems to be *much* slower than rsync.

Finally, you can set up a VPN between the two machines. This involves the most work, and either of the above solutions are much easier, but it would solve the problem of a flaky network connection. And as some people have noted, this can also be flaky. It *can* work if the VPN is very aggressive about reestablishing connections, as OpenVPN is, but the above solutions are much better.

Comment: In order to make this work, you'll need to use the `--partial` flag (or something that implies `--partial` like `--inplace`) otherwise whenever the transfer is interrupted, the partial transfer will be deleted and you'll have to start again.

Comment: Rsync definitely the way to go... Or robocopy for windows.

Comment: How exactly would a VPN help with a flakey connection?

Comment: The VPN software (e.g. OpenVPN) can reconnect automatically in the background, transparently to any applications that are running over the VPN.

Comment: @ErikA My thoughts precisely - VPN over flakey link = flakey VPN that's always having to restart. It only adds a second level to the problem which is that the transport software must be able to restart file transfer exactly where it was interrupted.

Comment: I didn't say it was the best solution, or even a _good_ solution, just that it is _a_ solution. :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I see where you're going with this and the auto-link reestablishment while the transfer program retries (if timeouts aren't exceeded) might actually help if the overhead doesn't exacerbate the weak link issues. Uggh! been there, no fun.

Comment: I find it's best to not have a flaky network in the first place. Then again, we have to live in the real world...

Comment: It's actually not a solution at all, at least not for this problem. Your statement that it "solves the flaky connection problem" is patently false. VPN does nothing of the sort.  With VPN, applications still need to be aware of the situation, and restart when the connection comes back up. VPN does nothing but add complexity and overhead. Your rsync recommendation is good. Simple, robust, easy to troubleshoot. I'd recommend that the OP just use rsync.

Comment: rsync sometimes hangs too... and when it doesn't, on a large filesystem it often doesn't reach the next file which needs transfering ("receiving incremental file list") before the connection is lost and it retries.

Comment: I think maybe a short `--timeout` with a bash script that checks exit code `$?` and retries inside a while loop is the only way. Be sure to use `--partial` too.